# Incomplete implementation warning in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have four to five view controller in each of them it show incomplete implementation
One ViewController is below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "CereniaAppDelegate.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController  <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    IBOutlet UIButton*homeButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton*economicDataButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton*riskButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton*financialImpactButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton*probabilitiesButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton*enterButton;
}



-(IBAction)enterButtonAction;
-(IBAction)homeButtonAction;
-(IBAction)economicDataButtonAction;
-(IBAction)riskButtonAction;
-(IBAction)financialImpactButtonAction;
-(IBAction)probabilitiesButtonAction;

@end
```

Implementaion

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "EconomicDataViewController.h"
#import "ProbabilitiesViewController.h"
#import "RiskViewController.h"
#import "FinancialImpactViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController

-(IBAction)homeButtonAction{

}

-(IBAction)enterButtonAction{   
    EconomicDataViewController*targetContrlloer=[[EconomicDataViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetContrlloer animated:YES];
}


-(IBAction)economicDataButtonAction{
    EconomicDataViewController*targetContrlloer=[[EconomicDataViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetContrlloer animated:YES];
}



-(IBAction)riskButtonAction{
    RiskViewController*targetContrlloer=[[RiskViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetContrlloer animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)financialImpactButtonAction{
    FinancialImpactViewController*targetContrlloer=[[FinancialImpactViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetContrlloer animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)probabilitiesButtonAction{
    ProbabilitiesViewController*targetContrlloer=[[ProbabilitiesViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetContrlloer animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {       
    // return YES;
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation); 
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc {   
    [super dealloc];

    [homeButton release];
    [economicDataButton release];
    [riskButton release];
    [probabilitiesButton release];
    [enterButton release];
}

@end
```

Comment: could u plz post ur error

Comment: @Gill-TheIronMan error is incomplete implementation protocol method not found

Comment: Check your CereniaAppDelegate.h file for method declarations. It's possible, though not likely, that something in there may not be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you dont implement the delegate methods for UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource. Do that and the error should disappear.

Comment: how to add that can you please help me thanks

Comment: Yes, you have to implement the delegate methods for whatever delegates your view controller has. I don't know what they are for the other ones because you didn't post them.

Answer (score 0):

Make the property of all the UIButtons you have and @synthesize it in your .m file.

like:

```
MainViewController.h

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController  <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    UIButton*homeButton;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *homeButton;
```

```
MainViewController.m

@synthesize homeButton;
```

Comment: and it is neccessary to release them in dealloc or not

Comment: yes of course it is necessary

Comment: it is a good practice to put dealloc

Comment: mean if i have 100 variable which i am declaring and synthesing all i have to release in deal loc

Comment: whatever value you retain. you have to release it also.

Comment: i did not get it mean all value which i have assigned or used i have release them

Comment: you can see that I define retain in @property. and whenever you retain any value it will occupy some space in memory so when dealloc call it will release your value from the memory.